# How to build project whose dependencies depend on another version of a project dependency

Tags: go, dependency-management, go-modules, vendoring

Imagine you have a project which requires two modules `A` and `B`. I will call the project module `P`. Let's say that `P` requires `A v1.0.0`, `B v1.1.0` and that `A` requires `B v1.0.0`. Furthermore `B` did not adhered  semantic versioning rules thus the version change from `v1.0.0 -> v1.1.0` introduced a breaking API change. So 
`P` only builds with `v1.1.0` and `A` only builds with `v1.0.0`.

Dependency graph:

```
P -> A (v1.0.0) -> B(v1.0.0)
P -> B (v1.1.0)
```

Is there any way to build this project with different versions. I heared about **vendoring** but I'm not sure if this would cause the dependency to use a different `B` module version.

And if it could provide a solution for the conflicting package versions, does the go tool recognize modules using vendoring if the dependencies do not include a vendor folder (some people say, you should not upload the vendor folder) in their git repository (In this case module `A` does not ship with a vendor folder, but the developer called `go mod vendor` locally), does the go get command respect vendor folders of dependencies (or can it detect that the module used vendoring without an upstream vendor folder)?

Comment: You will have to import B in P  with some V2 prefix. Read this related thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602028/two-version-of-same-dependency-lower-version-getting-ignored.

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a conflict the module system cannot resolve. Since Go uses semantic versioning it will try to get B v1.1.0 to resolve both dependencies and then the build will break if A cannot work with B 1.1.0.

The best way to resolve it is to fix B by not breaking the API in a non-major version.

Lacking that, you could *fork* B into a separate module (with a different module name from the original B) and use an old version in A. Create `BFORK=Bv1.0.0`, and then you'll have:

```
P -> B (v1.0.0)
A -> BFORK vX.X.X
```

Comment: Does that mean the only solution is to manually rewrite the code of **all** my dependencies (if they all use different incompatible versions of dependencies I use in my own module) to be compatible with the new API?

Comment: @Sebi2020 if you fork it you could just rewrite the imports. I updated the answer with more details